# Default values for Xmx, Xms, MaxPermSize on non-server-class machines

Tags: jvm, jvm-arguments

What are the default values for the following options in Java 6 on a *non-server-class machine*?

- -Xmx
- -XX:MaxPermSize

Oracle's [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gc-ergonomics.html) states that:

> On server-class machines running the server VM, the garbage collector (GC) has changed from the previous serial collector (-XX:+UseSerialGC) to a parallel collector (-XX:+UseParallelGC).

and

> On server-class machines running either VM (client or server) with the parallel garbage collector (-XX:+UseParallelGC) the initial heap size and maximum heap size have changed

The page doesn't describe the defaults for non-server-class machines, only that, for example, the initial heap size is "a reasonable minimum". Looking at [the 'man page'](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) for the `java` command there is the following against `-Xms`:

> The default value is chosen at runtime based on system configuration

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Default values for JDK 1.6.0_29 on Windows 7/32-bit:

```
-Xmx256m
-XX:MaxPermSize=64m
```

Also value of these option can be printed by following command:

```
java -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version 2>&1
```

Then look for MaxHeapSize and MaxPermSize keys and see default values.

```
uintx InitialHeapSize                          := 199947456       {product}
uintx MaxHeapSize                              := 268435456       {product}           
uintx MaxPermSize                               = 67108864        {pd product}
```

[Here](https://chriswhocodes.com/hotspot_options_jdk11.html) is the Ultimate HotSpot VM Options Cheat Sheet with defaults and descriptions for last 5 versions of JDK (7, 8, 9, 10 & 11).

Comment: I get *Unrecognized VM option '+PrintFlagsFinal'* when I try to run `java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal`

Comment: Svish, what is version of your JVM?

Comment: Doesn't work with `1.5.0_22`, but works with `1.7.0_07`, so was this added in 1.6 or something?

Comment: What does "no default" mean here? What is the default when there is no default?

Comment: Sorry, default value for -Xms option is stored with InitialHeapSize key.

Comment: Note that `java -XX:+PrintFlagFinal` outputs to `stderr`, so redirect with `2>&1` when grepping, e.g.: `java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal 2>&1 | grep PermSize`

Comment: Permanent Generation has been removed as of Java 1.8 - http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/122 - so there is no MaxPermSize for 1.8 onwards