# Need to check MaxPermSize : Unrecognized VM option

Tags: java, tomcat7

How do I check `maxpermsize` from command line? Getting error `unrecorgnized VM options`. Version is below

```
D:\apps\Tomcat\bin>java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal
Unrecognized VM option '+PrintFlagsFinal'
Could not create the Java virtual machine.

D:\apps\Tomcat\bin>java -version
java version "1.6.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_20-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 16.3-b01, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 1):

The VM option is not supported in your current JVM version. From [this article](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073830/core-java/hotspot-jvm-options-displayed---xx--printflagsinitial-and--xx--printflagsfinal.html), it seems available in Java 6u23.

Comment: @Rahul http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27041001/how-can-i-find-the-default-maxpermsize-when-xxprintflagsfinal-is-not-supporte may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a debugger to inspect the actual value:

`gdb -q java -ex run -ex "print MaxPermSize" -ex quit`