# How to reSet the defalut heap size for an Applet program run on the client?

Tags: java, jvm, applet, heap-memory

Before i ask this question i had glanced over the above posts
[[How is the default java heap size determined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667483/how-is-the-default-java-heap-size-determined])
[[Setting JVM heap size at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/763295/setting-jvm-heap-size-at-runtime])
[[How can I find the default MaxPermSize when -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal is not supported?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27041001/how-can-i-find-the-default-maxpermsize-when-xxprintflagsfinal-is-not-supporte])
but they seems not meet my need. i'm running an Applet on the client browser ,once i do request a large data from the server my client JVM will break down with error info "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space".So i try to find a way to increase my JVM's heap size shown in the pics but it does'nt
seem work.So now i have no idea to deal with it.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2yH0.png)

thanks advance.